# Centos httpd apache http server fails to start

Tags: apache, centos, openstack, httpd.conf, openstack-horizon

I have open stack running and it was working fine I've rebooted and since have been unable to restart httpd

```
[root@h30 ~]# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
       └─openstack-dashboard.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-09-01 14:11:07 BST; 2min 13s ago
 Docs: man:httpd(8)
       man:apachectl(8)
Process: 10030 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 10027 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 9944 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/manage.py compress --force (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 9919 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 10027 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 01 14:10:46 h30 python[9919]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/help-panel/help...ive.js'
Sep 01 14:10:46 h30 python[9919]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/help-panel/help...pec.js'
Sep 01 14:10:46 h30 python[9919]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/help-panel/help...l.html'
Sep 01 14:10:46 h30 python[9919]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/help-panel/help...ule.js'
Sep 01 14:10:46 h30 python[9919]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/help-panel/help...pec.js'
Sep 01 14:11:07 h30 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 01 14:11:07 h30 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 01 14:11:07 h30 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 01 14:11:07 h30 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Sep 01 14:11:07 h30 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

and I have no idea whats causing the issue to be honest, any help would be great.

Here is the error log

```
[Wed Aug 31 17:23:03.796739 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4346] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Aug 31 17:23:06.653781 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4346] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Aug 31 17:23:31.884455 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7547] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed Aug 31 17:23:31.885805 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 7547] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Aug 31 17:23:31.902192 2016] [so:warn] [pid 7547] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Aug 31 17:23:31.902233 2016] [so:warn] [pid 7547] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Aug 31 17:23:31.905613 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7547] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 31 17:23:32.100865 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7547] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 31 17:23:32.100922 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7547] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Aug 31 18:35:11.515126 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7547] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Aug 31 19:22:27.955740 2016] [core:notice] [pid 17956] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed Aug 31 19:22:27.968206 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 17956] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Aug 31 19:22:27.984913 2016] [so:warn] [pid 17956] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Aug 31 19:22:27.984949 2016] [so:warn] [pid 17956] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Aug 31 19:22:27.988204 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 17956] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 31 19:22:28.303754 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17956] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 31 19:22:28.303816 2016] [core:notice] [pid 17956] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Sep 01 09:35:49.397054 2016] [core:notice] [pid 20080] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Sep 01 09:35:49.399094 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 20080] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Sep 01 09:35:49.415550 2016] [so:warn] [pid 20080] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 09:35:49.415588 2016] [so:warn] [pid 20080] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 09:35:49.418833 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 20080] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Sep 01 09:35:49.712957 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20080] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 01 09:35:49.713022 2016] [core:notice] [pid 20080] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Sep 01 10:19:18.114919 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20080] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Sep 01 10:22:37.210697 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5401] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Sep 01 10:22:37.212740 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 5401] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Sep 01 10:22:37.228616 2016] [so:warn] [pid 5401] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 10:22:37.228654 2016] [so:warn] [pid 5401] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 10:22:37.231944 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 5401] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Sep 01 10:22:37.522692 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5401] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 01 10:22:37.522741 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5401] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Sep 01 13:20:14.419086 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5401] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Sep 01 13:20:48.116596 2016] [core:notice] [pid 41924] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Sep 01 13:20:48.118260 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 41924] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Sep 01 13:20:48.133601 2016] [so:warn] [pid 41924] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 13:20:48.133632 2016] [so:warn] [pid 41924] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 13:20:48.136768 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 41924] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Sep 01 13:20:48.396768 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 41924] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 01 13:20:48.396822 2016] [core:notice] [pid 41924] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Sep 01 13:21:00.502249 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 41924] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Sep 01 13:21:25.497407 2016] [core:notice] [pid 44854] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Sep 01 13:21:25.498739 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 44854] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Sep 01 13:21:25.514803 2016] [so:warn] [pid 44854] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 13:21:25.514842 2016] [so:warn] [pid 44854] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 13:21:25.518264 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 44854] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Sep 01 13:21:25.709404 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 44854] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 01 13:21:25.709456 2016] [core:notice] [pid 44854] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Sep 01 13:27:32.427493 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 44854] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Sep 01 13:30:35.056150 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5096] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Sep 01 13:30:35.058238 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 5096] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Sep 01 13:30:35.075005 2016] [so:warn] [pid 5096] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 13:30:35.075040 2016] [so:warn] [pid 5096] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Sep 01 13:30:35.078421 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 5096] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Sep 01 13:30:35.374300 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5096] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 01 13:30:35.374357 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5096] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Sep 01 13:37:17.885730 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5096] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

Comment: I would start by looking in your apache error log.

Comment: You need to run status with the -l switch to see the full error message. `Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.`Many times you can't see it all. Also that doesn't appear to be the error log file. Look at the one in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: well Panama that where i copied the text from

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any configuration changes? Does just rebooting the system is causing the issue? The error log does not showing any error.Can you enable the 'debug' level logging and try to restart your httpd service? and share the logs.

From the logs it seems you apache was started but immediately after few seconds it's shutdown.So,something is causing this shutdown.Have you configured any cron job for such service?

```
Thu Sep 01 13:20:48.396768 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 41924] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
...
[Thu Sep 01 13:21:00.502249 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 41924] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out SSLSessionCache was causing the issue

I had to go into /etc/httpd/conf.d ssl.conf

and comment out

`#SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)`